# ASP.NET Core MVC - How to add other attributes from referenced table in drop-down in View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm using ASP.NET Core v3 MVC with Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise.

I have database like this:

[image: ER model of sample database]

I'm using database first approach to generate models for that database. 
After that I'm adding following type of controller for `product_info` table:

[image]

Which will also generate Views. My question is - how can I display attributes from other tables in drop-down of `Create` View.

Here is example of what I mean:

[image]

I don't need complete solution, though it could be useful, any hints or pointers on how to do it would suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is full solution with fix for various problems I've encountered:

**MODEL**

1. Create folder in your project and call it `ViewModel`
2. Create class in that folder and call it `ProductInfoViewModel.cs`.Here is full content of `ProductInfoViewModel.cs`:

   `namespace ProductTest.ViewModels
   {
       public class ProductInfoViewModel
       {

           public int ProductId { get; set; }
           public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ProductName { get; set; } = new List<SelectListItem>();

           public int CategoryId { get; set; }
           public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategoryName { get; set; } = new List<SelectListItem>();

           public int SubcategoryId { get; set; }
           public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SubcategoryName { get; set; } = new List<SelectListItem>();

       }
   }`

Initialization with `new List<SelectListItem>();` is important so you don't get `NULL reference error`.

**CONTROLLER**

4. Under  `// GET: ProductInfoes/Create` add logic for getting data from database and loading it to `ProductInfoViewModel` object :

   `public IActionResult Create()        {
              // Hooks on databse to get list of Products
               var products = (from m in _context.Product
                                 select new SelectListItem
                                 {
                                     Value = m.ProductId.ToString(),
                                     Text = m.ProductName
                                 }).ToList();

               // Create new instance of our ViewModels.ProductInfoViewModel(()
               var vm = new ViewModels.ProductInfoViewModel();

               // Fill in ProductName in ProductInfoViewModel with list fetch from database
               vm.ProductName = new SelectList(products, "Value", "Text").Where(products => products != null);
               // Do same thing to Category and Subcategory
               var categories = (from m in _context.Category
                select new SelectListItem{
                    Value = m.CategoryId.ToString(),
                    Text = m.CategoryName
                }).ToList();
               vm.CategoryName = new SelectList(categories, "Value", "Text").Where(categories => categories != null);
               var subcategories = (from m in _context.Subcategory
                                 select new SelectListItem
                                 {
                                     Value = m.SubcategoryId.ToString(),
                                     Text = m.SubcategoryName
                                 }).ToList();
               vm.SubcategoryName = new SelectList(subcategories, "Value", "Text").Where(subcategories => subcategories != null);
               //Pass that model to View
               return View(vm);
           }`

**VIEW**

5. than go to `Views/ProductInfoes/Create.cshtml` file.
6. Add following code:

```html
@model ProductTest.ViewModels.ProductInfoViewModel

@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h1>Create</h1>
<h4>ProductInfo</h4>
<hr />

<form asp-action="Create">
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.ProductId, Model.ProductName, "--Select--")
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.CategoryId, Model.CategoryName, "--Select--")
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.SubcategoryId, Model.SubcategoryName, "--Select--")
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
</div>
</form>
<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

If you go to your Create page, something like:

```
https://localhost:44382/ProductInfoes/Create
```

and you will get this:

[image]

Click `Create` after you choose from dropdown. And if you go back to index page you'll see that product is successfully added on the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a viewmodel to display attributes in other model.

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Model1Items{ get; set; }
    public int SelectedId { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
var items = (from m in db.Model1s
         select new SelectListItem{
             Value = m.Id,
             Text = m.Name
         }).ToList(); 

var vm = new ViewModel();
vm.Model1Items = new SelectList(items, "Value", "Text");
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedId, Model.Model1Items, "--Select--")
```

Comment: Can you change this example to show only Category info in drop list? I'm also not really sure where controller code goes? I should add it in // GET: ProductInfoes/Create
        public IActionResult Create() I guess